# I need a Page rule for cloudflare redirection of specific url to internal page on 3rd party domain

Tags: redirect, cloudflare

I need a a page rule for cloudflare to only redirect 1 specific url (home page) to the the specific url of a 3rd party domain

so www.domain1.com (homepage only) to go to www.domain2/specific-page

All other urls of domain 1 to go nowhere

can you help ? thanks Art

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple "forwarding URL" page rule.  see attached picture:

[image: attached image]

Comment: What does the leading asterisk do? rather than having no asterisk?

Comment: If you left it out what would happen?

Comment: Sorry this is apparently unnecessary. (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-Configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-#understand-wildcard-matching-and-referencing)  I create a lot more routes for workers than page rules and routes require you to match the URL protocol as well. Apparently you can just use www.domain1.com for your page rule.